# How do I filter a dataframe by unique values in two columns in R?

Tags: r

I have this dataframe:

```
      [,1]            [,2]           
 [1,] "CHC.AU.Equity" "SGP.AU.Equity"
 [2,] "CMA.AU.Equity" "SGP.AU.Equity"
 [3,] "AJA.AU.Equity" "AOG.AU.Equity"
 [4,] "AJA.AU.Equity" "GOZ.AU.Equity"
 [5,] "AJA.AU.Equity" "SCG.AU.Equity"
 [6,] "ABP.AU.Equity" "AOG.AU.Equity"
 [7,] "AOG.AU.Equity" "FET.AU.Equity"
 [8,] "LIC.AU.Equity" "VRF.AU.Equity"
```

How would one filter this such that only the first instance of each string from EITHER column is included, i.e. these are trades for stocks, and I can only be in a stock once, not twice.

To be more clear, what I would want is the code to do this:

```
      [,1]            [,2]           
 [1,] "CHC.AU.Equity" "SGP.AU.Equity" <- STAY
 [2,] "CMA.AU.Equity" "SGP.AU.Equity" <- GONE
 [3,] "AJA.AU.Equity" "AOG.AU.Equity" <- STAY
 [4,] "AJA.AU.Equity" "GOZ.AU.Equity" <- GONE
 [5,] "AJA.AU.Equity" "SCG.AU.Equity" <- GONE
 [6,] "ABP.AU.Equity" "AOG.AU.Equity" <- GONE
 [7,] "AOG.AU.Equity" "FET.AU.Equity" <- GONE
 [8,] "LIC.AU.Equity" "VRF.AU.Equity" <- STAY
```

Which would produce:

```
      [,1]            [,2]           
 [1,] "CHC.AU.Equity" "SGP.AU.Equity"
 [3,] "AJA.AU.Equity" "AOG.AU.Equity"
 [8,] "LIC.AU.Equity" "VRF.AU.Equity"
```

I just got this, which seems to work, but I think it's kind of clunky. Let me know if there is some more elegant way to do this, or if this is flawed (df name is 'test'):

```
> test[rowSums(t(matrix(duplicated(as.vector(t(test))), nrow = 2))) == 0,]
     [,1]            [,2]           
[1,] "CHC.AU.Equity" "SGP.AU.Equity"
[2,] "AJA.AU.Equity" "AOG.AU.Equity"
[3,] "LIC.AU.Equity" "VRF.AU.Equity"
```

Comment: That will not account for the instance where it is not duplicated in both columns, but is duplicated across the columns.

Comment: What do the two columns represent?

Comment: They are pairs trades. I would not like to be long a stock in one pair trade, only to short it in another - essentially trading against myself.